# Drupal 7, listing users by custom field values

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, custom-fields

I created a custom field for a user's hometown, let's call it "field_home", that is required for every user when they register an account. They can only select certain text values from a list.

Is there any way I can add a "Hometown" column in admin/people, which lists every user's field_home value along with their user name and roles?

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a new view. You can build a better view than the one provided in `admin/people` in no time.

Add your own custom fields, edit/cancel-account links and filtering criteria. That'd be much easier and faster.